# Travel information and passport

Tags: email, confidentiality

I travel a lot and I am looking a good way to send my travel information, like hostel, passports etc. to send to my family before leaving.

This information is confidential. Actually, I am using a Zip to send this information to my family by email, but I am sure there's a better way to do it.

I do not trust sites like Microsoft, Google, or Facebook. They get a lot of information on us, so I did not want to give them more.

Comment: It's going to depend on the technical capabilities of your family. Also, why do you think that there is a better way than an encrypted zip file? Is there something you are not happy with?

Comment: @schroeder Zip files may use ZipCrypto which is trivially broken. Only 3rd party archive software like WinRar support AES, if I recall correctly. Not to mention there is no filename encryption. Something like 7zip would be better, as it both encrypts filenames and uses PBKDF2 for key derivation.

Comment: @forest whoops, you're totally right, revising my answer.

Comment: @forest sure, but for good answers to help the OP, it would be nice to know why *he* sees a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some tool already exist on the market that will let know send some confidential information's by email.

Tool like [Privnote](https://privnote.com/), [XMedius SendSecure](https://www.xmedius.com/fr/), SendInc or [Secure Exchanges](https://www.secure-exchanges.com/packages.aspx).

From my point of view i prefer Secure Exchanges. It's fully integrated with Microsoft Outlook, Gmail or Office 365 and it's very cheeps in term of fees. Something like 2$ or 3$ CAD per month. They other solution cost a little bit Higer.

There are also Gmail that are working on a encrypted solution, but to be honnest, i think Gmail (Google) already get to much information's on us ..

Depend if you want pay or not. Zip could also be a good thing but will stay in your mailbox (sent item) and received item of your recipient

Answer (score 2):

I've shared fairly sensitive info with people over email and used 7zip do to it. As @forest points out, zip does not do encryption well.

Use the "encrypt with password" feature (or whatever it's called in your 7zip program). Select AES-256 encryption if it gives you the choice and pick a strong password. Don't email/text the password, instead read it to them over the phone or hand it to them on paper.

Assuming you chose a strong password, that zip file should be ok to email, put on Google drive, wtv. The one caveat is that zip doesn't encrypt the names of the files, so make sure there's no personal information in the file names.

Comment: If someone tells me that the files I sent to someone as .7z are busted, I'm gonna cry.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I use [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html) and for *really sensitive* information I use [Kleopatra (OpenPGP)](https://www.openpgp.org/software/kleopatra/) To use 7zip you have to right click the `.zip` and click `Add to archive` then find Encryption and add your password.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, ZipCrypto is unsecure for modern usage. Instead, third-party solutions must be used to encrypt a ZIP file with AES-256. *[7-ZIP](https://www.7-zip.org/)* provides a good solution on Windows which also supplies source code. Unfortunately, as of writing this, 7-Zip does not provide checksums or use public key cryptography to verify integrity.

I am fond of 7z file format. 7z is a compressed archive file format that supports several different data compression, encryption and pre-processing algorithms.

Using 7z with AES-256 on Linux. [7z command line with highest encryption: AES-256 + Encrypting the Filenames](https://askubuntu.com/questions/928275/7z-command-line-with-highest-encryption-aes-256-encrypting-the-filenames).

The ideas discussed above creates an archive (a file that is composed of one or more files along with metadata) and then encrypts that archive. We are treating the archive as a container. So, those filenames are also encrypted. A similar method could be done by creating a Tarball archive and then encrypting that. Then you can share the encrypted container even via compromised channels without the worry of the confidential files being divulged; not advisable but used to enforce my confidence in the method.

Alternatives exist:

**[NextCloud](https://nextcloud.com/)**

> Building self-hosted products that allow you to be productive without
>   losing control

So, you host NextCloud on your own server, then you control the server and its contents. NextCloud is open source.

**[MEGA](https://mega.nz/)**

> We make secure cloud storage simple. Create an account and get 50 GB* free on MEGA’s end-to-end encrypted cloud collaboration platform today!

Files are client-side encrypted and then sent to the MEGA. Hence, MEGA never sees the content, only encrypted files. MEGA is hosted in New Zealand. Despite being open source like NextCloud, MEGA requires you trust their servers have not been compromised, as it's deployed via JavaScript.

**[OnionShare](https://onionshare.org/)**

OnionShare is an open source tool that lets you securely and anonymously share a file of any size via the Tor network.

> It works by starting a web server, making it accessible as a Tor Onion
>   Service, and generating an unguessable URL to access and download the
>   files. It does not require setting up a separate server or using a
>   third party file-sharing service. You host the files on your own
>   computer and use a Tor Onion Service to make it temporarily accessible
>   over the internet. The receiving user just needs to open the URL in
>   Tor Browser to download the file.

**[Cryptomator](https://cryptomator.org/)**

Free client-side encryption for your cloud files.

See Cryptomator's [security](https://cryptomator.org/security/) page

What about communicating the symmetric (decryption) key. So the receiver of the container can access the files. Asymmetric encryption is the answer.

**[GPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard)**

> GnuPG is a complete and free implementation of the OpenPGP standard as
>   defined by RFC4880 (also known as PGP). GnuPG allows you to encrypt
>   and sign your data and communications; it features a versatile key
>   management system, along with access modules for all kinds of public
>   key directories.

[image: Encryption and Decryption using gpg]

This idea is a key-pair. You have two keys a public key (used to encrypt data) and a private key (used to decrypt data). As shown in the above image, the plaintext is encrypted with the public key producing ciphertext. This ciphertext can be decrypted using the private key to produce the original plaintext. This will be your key exchange mechanism.

You share your public key with people, and when they want to send you a secure message (plaintext) they encrypt the message with your public key and send you the ciphertext. Then only you can read that ciphertext, as you hold the corresponding private key.

**Using 7z with AES-256 and GPG together**

Now you follow the ideas discussed above:

- Archive the files into a 7z archive
- Encrypt the archive 7z archive and filenames using AES-256
- Encrypt the symetric password used to encrypt the 7z archive with the recipriant's public key
- Send the encrypted 7z archive via your chosen method (email, Facebook, Google Drive, etc...)
- Send the ciphertext (GPG message) via your chosen method